# How to execute functions sequentially in an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel which calls certain functions from within the device and gives some output. I'm processing an image such that first a vertical pass is performed and then a horizontal pass is done. At present I'm calling the kernel twice, from the host side, by modifying the values of the arguments in each call.

```
kernel void image_filter(a, b, c, d)
{
    func1(a, b, c, d);
    if(<condition>)
        func2(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Now I want to modify the kernel such that it can be called only once and both the horizontal as well as the vertical passes are performed.

```
kernel void image_filter(a, b, c, d)
{
    // Vertical pass
    func1(a, b, c, d);
    if(<condition>)
        func2(a, b, c, d);

    // When execution of the above functions is complete
    // Horizontal pass
    // Some computation
    func1(a, b, c, d);
    if(<condition>)
        func2(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Note that there is data dependency between the vertical and horizontal passes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible with a single kernel enqueue, you must use two kernel enqueues.

Why? Because *not all work items start before others finish*. You have no control over that (it is up to the runtime). And since you indicated that there is data dependency between the vertical and horizontal passes, you need all of the first set of work items to complete before the second set start. Therefore, two kernel enqueues.

TL;DR: There is no global synchronization within a kernel (only workgroup synchronization). Use two enqueues.

Comment: Can I use ``barrier()`` here?

Comment: No, you can't use `barrier`. It's for workgroup synchronization. You need global synchronization, and the only way to do that is by enqueuing multiple kernels.

Comment: What if I have just one work group with n work items?

Comment: Q: What if I have just one work group with n work items?
A: Only if N is small. Most runtimes limit work group sizes to fairly small numbers.